# Difficulties in programming of messenger Telegram on C#

Tags: c#, api, rpc, messenger, telegram

I try to send a code(*TLRequestAuthSendCode*) but it doesn't come. In what there can be a problem?

Part of code:

```
TLContext tlContext = new TLApiContext();
TcpClient tcpClient = new TcpClient();
tcpClient.Connect(connections[0].getAddress(), (int)connections[0].getPort());
TLRequestAuthSendCode tlRequestAuthSendCode = new TLRequestAuthSendCode("PHONE_NUMBER",
0, 19114, "TOKEN", "en");
tlRequestAuthSendCode.serializeBody(new StreamWriter(tcpClient.GetStream()));
```

Comment: show us some code, and try to create a [SSCCE](http://www.sscce.org)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get started with [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32809138/44080), but I have written it in vb.net, not C#.

It will walk you through getting started building your own Telegram-API from scratch.

Also try and get familiar with the online documentation, it's *hard* but the step by step explanation I gave in that [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32809138/44080) above on generating your **AuthKey**, should get you started.

Good Luck

Answer (score 2):

can you debug your code and tell if

`tcpClient.Connect(connections[0].getAddress(),`

Connections[0] has a value?

I'd suggest you change your code to the following:

```
        public void run() {
        connections = new ConnectionInfo[]{
            new ConnectionInfo(1, 0, "149.154.167.40", 443)
        };

        apiState = new ApiState(connections);
        doReqCode(connections);

        private void doReqCode(connections){

        var args = new SocketAsyncEventArgs();
```

I don't see where the code could break, maybe a more detailed description of your problem would be helpful

Answer (score 1):

`TcpClient tcpClient = new TcpClient();`

As i tried the code, it mostly seemd to me as if the port was either blocked or already in use. Maybe u have a permission problem there. At least i didnt manage to get a Socket to work with the code like that.
Also i didnt dive to deep in your code, but you are using port 443. This is a reserved port with limited access.